# Adapter not displaying document fields on cardview but able to read the number of documents in a firestore collection

Tags: firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

I have an adapter that's supposed to populate my recycler view. The adapter seems to be working because it is able to read the exact number of documents in the firestore collection. However, I need it to populate each cardview on the recycler view with the fields in the documents. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

[Output from emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W69pR.png)

The code for populating the recyclerview.

public void listData(){

```
    mealModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    mealRV= view.findViewById(R.id.RVMealItems);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    mealRV.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    db= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    db.collection("meals").orderBy("Meal Name", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {

                    if(error != null){
                        if(progressDialog.isShowing()){
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Firestore error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }else {
                        assert value != null;
                        for(DocumentChange dc: value.getDocumentChanges()){
                            if(dc.getType()== DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
                                mealModelArrayList.add(dc.getDocument().toObject(Meal_Model.class));
                                available_meals_adapter= new Available_Meals_Adapter(getActivity(), mealModelArrayList);
                                mealRV.setAdapter(available_meals_adapter);
                                    if(progressDialog.isShowing()){
                                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                            }
                            available_meals_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

My Model Class

public class Meal_Model {

```
private String meal_name;
private String price;
private int meal_imageSrc;

public Meal_Model(String meal_name, String price, int meal_imageSrc) {
    this.meal_name = meal_name;
    this.price = price;
    this.meal_imageSrc = meal_imageSrc;
}

public Meal_Model(){

}

public String getMeal_name() {
    return meal_name;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}


public int getMeal_imageSrc() {
    return meal_imageSrc;
}
```

}

My adapter

public class Available_Meals_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Meal_Model> Meal_ModelArrayList;

public Available_Meals_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Meal_Model> meal_ModelArrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    Meal_ModelArrayList = meal_ModelArrayList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public OrdersViewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.pending_item, parent, false);
    return new OrdersViewholder(view);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OrdersViewholder holder, int position) {

    Meal_Model model = Meal_ModelArrayList.get(position);
    holder.orderMealNameTV.setText("Name"+model.getMeal_name());
    holder.orderMealPriceTV.setText("$" + model.getPrice());
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(model.getMeal_imageSrc())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_baseline_no_food_24)
            .centerCrop()
    .into(holder.orderMealIV);

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Meal_ModelArrayList.size();
}
```

}

Comment: I did not quite understand how that duplicate answer, sir. Does the "Model Class" suppose to have the same exact field names as the document in the database at all times? @AlexMamo

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Just checked! It works now sir. Thank you so much. @AlexMamo